# PDFDocument writeToURL not working

Tags: objective-c, pdf, pdfkit

I am working with PDFDocument and PDFView. 
I'm able to open a file and display it.

But if I try to save it with a different URL via PDFDocument's "writeToURL:" it doesn't work.
I logged the fileURL in the console, which was exactly the same like I typed in the save-Panel. But it doesn't write the Document to that URL.

I tried the same with a new allocated PDFDocument, which was working like i expected it. 
Do I forget about any access-issues?

Here's my code:

```
NSURL* fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] init];
NSSavePanel* savePanel;
savePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
NSArray* fileTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"pdf", nil];
[savePanel setAllowedFileTypes:fileTypes];
if([savePanel runModal] == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
{
    fileURL = savePanel.URL;
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"failed to save file");
    fileURL = nil;
}
[pdfView.document writeToURL:fileURL];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check if pdfView.document is nil.

Comment: Have you checked the write permission of that folder/filePath ?

Comment: In your code you assign savePanel.URL to a variable named "fileURL", but you write your document using another variable named  "filePath" ??? Typo in your question ?

Comment: "filePath" == "fileURL", I just forgot to change that here. (fixed)

Like Suresh mentioned, the document was nil.
I fxed it now. 
 
Thanks for your answers

Comment: I can't believe there is no version of `[PDFDocument writeToURL]` that returns an `NSError`, so you can get a meaningful failure code.  Try this code and see what the error is: `NSData *data = [pdfView.document dataRepresentation];
[data writeToURL:fileURL options:0 error:&error];`.  Check the return value from `writeToURL`!